# How Do I Change The KDE Lock Screen Shortcut From A Script?

Tags: bash, kde

Each time I reinstall I re-map the lock screen global shortcut manually to Win/Super+L.

How can I do this from the command line so that I can subsequently run it from a script?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that global keyboard shortcuts shortcuts are stored in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`. It's structured in headered sections like an INI file. You might be able to add the shortcut if you can add it to that file in the correct location.

Source: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=151477